# How to use JEST to test the time course of recursive functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I write a test using JEST. I do not know how to test promise recursion in JEST.

In this test, the retry function that performs recursion is the target of the test until the promise is resolved.

```
export function retry<T>(fn: () => Promise<T>, limit: number = 5, interval: number = 1000): Promise<T> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fn()
      .then(resolve)
      .catch((error) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          // Reject if the upper limit number of retries is exceeded
          if (limit === 1) {
            reject(error);

            return;
          }
          // Performs recursive processing of callbacks for which the upper limit number of retries has not been completed
          try {
            resolve(retry(fn, limit - 1, interval));
          } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
          }
        }, interval);
      });
  });
}
```

Perform the following test on the above retry function.

1. retry() is resolved in the third run. The first, second and third times are called every 1000 seconds respectively.

I thought it would be as follows when writing these in JEST.

```
jest.useFakeTimers();

describe('retry', () => {
  // Timer initialization for each test
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllTimers();
  });
  // Initialize timer after all tests
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllTimers();
  });

  test('resolve on the third call', async () => {
    const fn = jest
      .fn()
      .mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('Async error'))
      .mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('Async error'))
      .mockResolvedValueOnce('resolve');

    // Test not to be called
    expect(fn).not.toBeCalled();
    // Mock function call firs execution
    await retry(fn);
    // Advance Timer for 1000 ms and execute for the second time
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);
    expect(fn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    // Advance Timer for 1000 ms and execute for the third time
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);
    expect(fn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);

    await expect(fn).resolves.toBe('resolve');
  });

});
```

As a result, it failed in the following error.

```
● retry › resolve on the third call
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 30000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: 

    > 16 |   test('resolve on the third call', async () => {
         |   ^
      17 |     jest.useFakeTimers();
      18 |     const fn = jest
      19 |       .fn()
```

I think that it will be manageable in the setting of JEST regarding this error. However, fundamentally, I do not know how to test promise recursive processing in JEST.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is so hard to testing with timer.

When you call `await retry(fn);` this mean you will wait until `retry` return a value, but the `setTimeout` has been blocked until you call `jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);` => this is main reason, because `jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);` never been called.

You can see my example, it is working fine with jest's fake timers.

```
  test("timing", async () => {
    async function simpleTimer(callback) {
      await callback();
      setTimeout(() => {
        simpleTimer(callback);
      }, 1000);
    }

    const callback = jest.fn();
    await simpleTimer(callback); // it does not block any things
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000); // then, this line will be execute
      await Promise.resolve(); // allow any pending jobs in the PromiseJobs queue to run
    }
    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(9);  // SUCCESS
  });
```

I think, you could skip test timer detail, just test about you logic: `fn` has been called 3 times, finally it return `"resolve"`

```
test("resolve on the third call", async () => {
    const fn = jest
      .fn()
      .mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error("Async error"))
      .mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error("Async error"))
      .mockResolvedValueOnce("resolve");

    // expect.assertions(3);

    // Test not to be called
    expect(fn).not.toBeCalled();
    // Mock function call firs execution

    const result = await retry(fn);

    expect(result).toEqual("resolve");

    expect(fn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
  });
```

**Note: remove all your fake timers** - `jest.useFakeTimers`

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of jest suggests that testing promises is fairly straightforward ( https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous )

They give this example (assume fetchData is returning a promise just like your retry function)

```
test('the data is peanut butter', () => {
  return fetchData().then(data => {
    expect(data).toBe('peanut butter');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @hoangdv this recursive setTimeout pattern is very tricky to test.  This is the only solution that worked for me after trying @hoangdv's (which gave me much inspiration).

Note I'm using a similar retry pattern around network Fetches.  I'm using React Testing Library to look for an error message that only appears when the retry function ran 3 times.

```
it('Shows file upload error on timeout', async () => {
            jest.useFakeTimers();
            setupTest();
            // sets up various conditions that trigger the underlying fetch


            while (
                screen.queryByText(
                    'There appears to be a network issue. Please try again in a few minutes.'
                ) === null
            ) {
                jest.runOnlyPendingTimers(); // then, this line will be execute
                await Promise.resolve(); // allow any pending jobs in the PromiseJobs queue to run

            }
            await waitFor(() => {
                expect(
                    screen.getByText(
                        'There appears to be a network issue. Please try again in a few minutes.'
                    )
                ).toBeInTheDocument();
            });
            jest.useRealTimers();
        });
```